# Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, json, database, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am new to using JSON,I'm trying to get data from a database on my server that just has positions in latitude and longitude, as well as a user name and a time stamp. I don't need to use a time stamp at the moment, and I seem to be getting into an issue I can't seem to figure out.

```
    String result = "";
    double Lat = 0;
    double Lng = 0;
    String title = "";
    try{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("removed");
                    HttpGet("Removed");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                System.out.println("Test while");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
            try{
                System.out.println("Test 7, last pass");
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                System.out.println("Test 8");
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    System.out.println("Test for");
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println("Test 9");
                    Lat= json_data.getDouble("Latitude");
                    System.out.println("Test 10 "+ Lat);
                    Lng = json_data.getDouble("Longitude");
                    System.out.println("Test 11 "+ Lng);
                    title= json_data.getString("User");
                    System.out.println("Test 12 "+ title );
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Lat,Lng)).title(title).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.zombie_marker)));
                    System.out.println("Test for end");
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                System.out.println("Test inner catch");
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                  Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Test middle catch");
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
              Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Test outer catch");
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
    }
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
}
```

This is the code I am using, and this is the log cat i am printing i have some print outs to see where I am.

```
    05-07 14:09:40.911: I/System.out(13775): Test while
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test 7, last pass
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test 8
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test for
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test 9
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test 10 31.767669
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test 11 -106.502012
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test 12 Zombie_1
    05-07 14:09:40.921: I/System.out(13775): Test middle catch
    05-07 14:09:40.921: E/log_tag(13775): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-07 14:09:40.921: E/log_tag(13775): Failed data was:
    05-07 14:09:40.921: E/log_tag(13775): [{"Longitude":"-106.502012","Latitude":"31.767669","User":"Zombie_1","Time":"2014-04-24 21:48:15"},{"Longitude":"0","Latitude":"0","User":"Zombie_0","Time":"2014-04-24 21:48:15"},{"Longitude":"-106.502012","Latitude":"31.767669","User":"Zombie_2","Time":"2014-04-24 21:49:52"},{"Longitude":"-106.507849","Latitude":"31.78073","User":"Zombie_3","Time":"2014-04-24 21:49:52"}]
```

so my PHP is working and sending me the data i need but I can't see to even see the issue. This is my first time using JSON so any help would be appreciated. Or any tips on reading data from a database on a server for Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's throwing the `NullPointerException`, but it's happening on this line:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(json_data.getDouble("Latitude"),json_data.getDouble("Longitude")))
.title(json_data.getString("User"))
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.zombie_marker)));
```

Split that line into multiple statements, update your Exception logging to include a stack trace, and run the code again.  Most logging frameworks will print a stack trace if they are told to log an Exception object.  If not, `e.printStackTrace()` can be used directly to print the stack trace to STDERR.  That should tell you what part of the complex statement is throwing the `NullPointerException`.

In general, complicated statements (like several you have) make debugging and quickly identifying errors more difficult than if individual statements are on separate lines.  It's more code to separate them, but it can enhance readability and debugging efforts.

Comment: Well this is how you use map markers in google maps, i have used it several other times with no issues the only one being that i am using the json values instead of hard coded ones.

Comment: I don't doubt this is the right way to use it.  Putting everything in a single statement makes tracking down NullPointerExceptions difficult.  I'm just advocating to extract the JSON values separately, then build the LatLng, build the icon, and then build the MarkerOptions.  Do those in separate statements, and I suspect you'll easily find the NPE.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't help. I believe the issue is else where but for some reason it is having an issue between the lines using map marker.

I converted the code and the issue is in the same line but the second exception on the middle try statement is being thrown. Not to mention my new log cat print out shows that all the variables are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It was a newbie mistake I Tried to add markers to a map that yet did not exist. Can't believe I over looked that.

Just moved this line to the top and it works fine.

mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Thanks for the help.